# RSA Encryption in metro style Application

Tags: microsoft-metro, rsa

I have public key modulus and public key exponent and I need to generate a public key and encrypt data in metro style application. in c# we have  RSAParameters class but I cannot find any thing  of such sort for metro style applications.

when I use the base64encoded public key directly received from the certificate and try  to import the key with the below code  I get an exception thrown ASN1 bad tag value met.
which i think is due to the invalid format of the data.

```
     //sample dummy key from certificate in base64encoded
     string key =   @"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";
       symmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asymmAlg = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("RSA_OAEP_SHA1");
       CryptographicKey publicKey = asymmAlg.ImportPublicKey(CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(key));
        string input64string ="encrypt this";
        IBuffer dataToEncrypt = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input64string);
        IBuffer encryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, dataToEncrypt, null);
```

Comment: I too am trying to accomplish this but have not found the correct structure replacement.

Comment: You may want to take a look at mi answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459390/import-public-rsa-key-from-certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `key` is the modulus part of the public key, whose length is 128. Consider the standard key exported from C# code in metro:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
CryptographicKey standardKeyPair = provider.CreateKeyPair(1024);
byte[] standardKey = standardKeyPair.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey).ToArray();
```

you can see the length of the byte[] standardKey is 140,which has 7 bits prefix and 5 bits tail. I don't know the reason, but I copied the extra 12 bits to the known key, it works. Hope this helps you:

```
public static IBuffer RsaEncrypt(this IBuffer dataToEncrypt, string publicKeyN)
{
    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);

    CryptographicKey standardKeyPair = provider.CreateKeyPair(1024);
    byte[] standardKey = standardKeyPair.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey).ToArray();
    var data_n = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(publicKeyN).ToArray();
    Array.Copy(data_n, 0, standardKey, 7, data_n.Length);
    var key = provider.ImportPublicKey(standardKey.AsBuffer(), CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);

    var result = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, dataToEncrypt, null);
    return result;          
}
```

Comment: The "extra bits" are probably the Exponent part of the key

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking:

```cs
public static IBuffer RsaEncrypt(byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, IBuffer data)
{
  var rsa = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaOaepSha1);
  var keyBlob = modulus.Concat(exponent).ToArray().AsBuffer();
  var publicKey = rsa.ImportPublicKey(keyBlob, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);
  return CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, data, null);
}
```

Of course, you can still use base64 strings as input/output if want, but you already know how to do that. :)

If you dig down to page 61 of [RFC3447](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) you will find that the public key format structure is just the modulus followed by the exponent, which is why I concatenated them.

Comment: The public key format structure is more than just the concatenation of the two values. It uses ASN.1 format, which includes extra header information.

Comment: @anton Thanks, but what does that mean in practice?  Can you provide an example please?

Comment: It means you need an ASN.1 implementation that can take a sequence of two integers and encode it to a byte array:

    var publicKey = new X509RsaPublicKey();
    publicKey.Modulus = new ASN1Integer(modulus);
    publicKey.Exponent = new ASN1Integer(exponent);
    rsa.ImportPublicKey(publicKey.GetBytes().AsBuffer(), CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);

Comment: @Anton - I can't find these classes anywhere except in Java.  You do realize this question was for C# in a Windows Store (WinRT) App?  Or do you know of some namespace I don't?

Comment: That was pseudo-code. Pure coincidence if the names match up to something in Java. .NET does not include an ASN.1 implementation, so you would have to write one yourself. There's an excellent overview of the ASN.1 format here: http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html