# WinRT RSA encryption from public key exponent/modulus

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, rsa

I'm trying to port this method from .NET 4.5 desktop app to a WinRT app:

```
static byte[] DotNetRsaEncrypt(string modulus, string exponent, byte[] data)
{
    var modulusBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(modulus);
    var exponentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(exponent);

    var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters { Modulus = modulusBytes, Exponent = exponentBytes };
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    var encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
    return encrypted;
}
```

After reading this [RSA Encryption in metro style Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880450/rsa-encryption-in-metro-style-application)

I tried the following:

```
static byte[] WinRtRsaEncrypt(string modulus, string exponent, byte[] data)
{        
    var modulusBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(modulus);
    var exponentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(exponent);

    var keyBlob = modulusBytes.Concat(exponentBytes).ToArray().AsBuffer();

    var rsa = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaOaepSha1);
    var key = rsa.ImportPublicKey(keyBlob, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);

    var encrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data.AsBuffer(), null);
    return encrypted;
}
```

But it does not work.

In order to get the same functionality as my desktop app...

- What `AsymmetricAlgorithmNames` should I pass to `OpenAlgorithm()`?
- What `CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType` should I pass to `ImportPublicKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

Following up on user1968335's hint, this worked for me.

First, in a C# application, use the following code to obtain a CspBlob from your modulus/exponent:

```
var exponent = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(exponentStr);
var modulus = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(modulusStr);

var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters { Modulus = modulus, Exponent = exponent };
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
var cspBlobString = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportCspBlob(false));
```

Then, in a WinRT application you can use that CspBlob to sign a piece of data like this:

```
private static string SignString(string data)
{
    string cspBlobString = //cspBlob
    var keyBlob = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(cspBlobString);

    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider rsa = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
    CryptographicKey key = rsa.ImportPublicKey(keyBlob, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Capi1PublicKey);

    IBuffer plainBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer encryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, plainBuffer, null);

    byte[] encryptedBytes;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(encryptedBuffer, out encryptedBytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}
```

If it matters, this is how I generated my asymmetric keys: http://43n141e.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/rsa-encryption-openssl-to-ruby-to-c-and_27.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [CryptoWinRT sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CryptoWinRT-54ff3d9f), `OpenAlgorithm(...)` method takes these values.

- RSA_PKCS1
- RSA_OAEP_SHA1
- RSA_OAEP_SHA256
- RSA_OAEP_SHA384

See also : [RSA cryptography between a WinRT and a .Net app](http://www.japf.fr/2013/05/rsa-cryptography-between-a-winrt-and-a-dotnet-app/)

Comment: Well, before asking my question, I of course tried all those values and their combinaisons. The link you provide does not use a modulus and an exponent for the public key.

Comment: After much digging here's how I solved this mess:

1) use .net to export a "CspBlob" from modulus & exponent
var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters { Modulus = modulus, Exponent = exponent };
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
var cspBlobString = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportCspBlob(false));

Comment: 2) use that cspBlobString with CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Capi1PublicKey
var keyBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(cspBlobString)
var rsa = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaOaepSha1);
var key = rsa.ImportPublicKey(keyBlob, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Capi1PublicKey);

all other conbinaison didn't work.
WinRT sucks

Comment: post your comment as answer, so all can get to know.

Comment: I used an approach similar to user1968335's, I'll post it as an aswer.